# PHP Changing Session Variables

Tags: php, session

I have a problem changing session variables after a user updates his profile.

My settings.php page, for example, sets the current `$_SESSION['first_name']` to a variable, like so:

```
session_start();
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
```

and in the form I can echo the first name like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($first_name); ?>">
```

Then after the user changes the value of the input and hits the submit button the form is processed on the same page like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $first_name = mysqli_prep($connection, $_POST ['first_name']);

  unset($_SESSION['first_name']);
  $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;

  redirect_to('settings.php');
  exit();
}
```

But when the page is refreshed using my redirect_to function, the session variable hasn't changed.

I do insert the change to a database, which I omitted from the code above for simplicity's sake, and the new value is inserted accurately, so I know the problem is with the session, not the input or form processing.

I tried adding `session_regenerate_id(true);` just before the redirect, but it does nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you `session_start()` in the change-handling script?

Comment: try to `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Well, it all happens on the same page. So, yes. It's at the very top.

Comment: I have tried var_dump($_SESSION); and it shows the variable has not changed to the new value.

Comment: what is this `mysqli_prep` may be here it is not returning correct value

Comment: I just added a new paragraph to my post explaining that I am inserting the value into a database and it does so correctly, so I know it's not the form processing that's the problem.

Comment: what that function will return

Comment: mysqli_prep just sanitizes the input using trim and mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: 2 things I would try: (1) echo `$firstname` after calling `mysqli_prep` to confirm it's returning the correct value. (2) After unsetting, set `$_SESSION` to some random string and see if that works

Comment: i am sure there is something wrong in that

Comment: Mark M, I echoed `$first_name` and removed the `redirect_to('settings.php');` line and now it works. It seems to be the redirect that's causing the issue.

Comment: why are you unsetting the SESSION instead of just changing the value?

Comment: That was one of the things I originally tried after doing some googling. Originally, I was not unsetting.

Comment: Try `unset($GLOBALS['_SESSION']['first_name']);` as described here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php `If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function ...`